# How can I check how old a piece of data is?

Tags: time

I have some content that I'm storing in a custom member profile field and I want to be able to check how old it is on the front end and show the user a message asking them to update it if it's more than 12 months old.

I have a 2nd custom field which I'm planning to use to store the 'updated date' but how can I compare that to the {current_time} variable and find out if there is an interval of more than 12 months?

Comment: which version of ee?

Comment: We're running 2.8.1 :)